# CKAN - Vector Storer Extension error

Tags: python, geospatial, ckan

I have installed CKAN on a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit system and everything was fine. I also installed correctly these extensions: geojson_preview wms_preview spatial_metadata spatial_query disqus pdf_preview spatialUI googleanalytics archiver contact

Now, I wanted to add vectorstorer extension but it is appearing an error that I don't have any idea how to solve. I would be grateful if someone can give me an advice to look for a solution to this:

```
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:08 2015] [error] Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clearing'" in <bound method PluginEnvironment.__del__ of  Services for Environment '<default>'
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:08 2015] [error] > ignored
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:08 2015] [error] Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clearing'" in <bound method PluginEnvironment.__del__ of  Services for Environment '<default>'
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:08 2015] [error] > ignored
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:08 2015] [error] Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method LGEOS320.__del__ of <shapely.geos.LGEOS320 object at 0x7f17a7016f58>> ignored
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:08 2015] [error] Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method LGEOS320.__del__ of <shapely.geos.LGEOS320 object at 0x7f17a7016f58>> ignored
Error opening file for reading: Permission denied
Error opening file for reading: Permission denied
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:11 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:11,447 WARNI [ckan.plugins.core] Plugin 'googleanalytics' is using deprecated interface IGenshiStreamFilter
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:11 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:11,564 DEBUG [ckanext.spatial.model.package_extent] Spatial tables defined in memory
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:11 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:11,567 DEBUG [ckanext.spatial.model.package_extent] Spatial tables already exist
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:12 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:12,258 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  / render time 0.605 seconds
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:12 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:12,999 WARNI [ckan.plugins.core] Plugin 'googleanalytics' is using deprecated interface IGenshiStreamFilter
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:13 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:13,120 DEBUG [ckanext.spatial.model.package_extent] Spatial tables defined in memory
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:13 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:13,123 DEBUG [ckanext.spatial.model.package_extent] Spatial tables already exist
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:13 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:13,385 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.002 seconds
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:31 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:31,405 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  / render time 0.628 seconds
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:31 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:31,499 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/en render time 0.002 seconds
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:37 2015] [error] Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clearing'" in <bound method PluginEnvironment.__del__ of  Services for Environment '<default>'
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:37 2015] [error] > ignored
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:37 2015] [error] Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clearing'" in <bound method PluginEnvironment.__del__ of  Services for Environment '<default>'
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:37 2015] [error] > ignored
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:37 2015] [error] Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method LGEOS320.__del__ of <shapely.geos.LGEOS320 object at 0x7f179efcb050>> ignored
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:37 2015] [error] Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method LGEOS320.__del__ of <shapely.geos.LGEOS320 object at 0x7f17a7020f58>> ignored
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:41,247 WARNI [ckan.plugins.core] Plugin 'googleanalytics' is using deprecated interface IGenshiStreamFilter
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205] mod_wsgi (pid=31654): Target WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205] mod_wsgi (pid=31654): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return context.create()
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return self.object_type.invoke(self)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     val = callable(*args, **kw)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware.py", line 57, in make_app
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     load_environment(conf, app_conf)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 232, in load_environment
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     p.load_all(config)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 134, in load_all
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     load(*plugins)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 149, in load
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     service = _get_service(plugin)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 255, in _get_service
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return plugin.load()(name=plugin_name)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1989, in load
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-vectorstorer/ckanext/vectorstorer/plugin.py", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     from ckanext.vectorstorer import resource_actions
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-vectorstorer/ckanext/vectorstorer/resource_actions.py", line 13, in <module>
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     from ckanext.publicamundi.model.resource_identify import ResourceIdentify
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205] ImportError: No module named resource_identify
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:41 2015] [error] 2015-02-06 08:34:41,993 WARNI [ckan.plugins.core] Plugin 'googleanalytics' is using deprecated interface IGenshiStreamFilter
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205] mod_wsgi (pid=31653): Target WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205] mod_wsgi (pid=31653): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi", line 10, in <module>
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return context.create()
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return self.object_type.invoke(self)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     val = callable(*args, **kw)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware.py", line 57, in make_app
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     load_environment(conf, app_conf)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 232, in load_environment
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     p.load_all(config)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 134, in load_all
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     load(*plugins)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 149, in load
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     service = _get_service(plugin)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 255, in _get_service
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     return plugin.load()(name=plugin_name)
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1989, in load
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-vectorstorer/ckanext/vectorstorer/plugin.py", line 7, in <module>
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     from ckanext.vectorstorer import resource_actions
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-vectorstorer/ckanext/vectorstorer/resource_actions.py", line 13, in <module>
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205]     from ckanext.publicamundi.model.resource_identify import ResourceIdentify
[Fri Feb 06 08:34:42 2015] [error] [client 10.0.26.205] ImportError: No module named resource_identify
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I considered what Denis advice me and I opened an issue to the team of publicamundi. They said me the following:

> This extension is not meant to be used as a standalone CKAN extension
>   (anymore). Instead, it's integrated as a plugin into
>   ckanext-publicamundi extension
>   (https://github.com/PublicaMundi/ckanext-publicamundi). Actually, the
>   error you have encountered is a module dependency from this "parent"
>   extension.
>
> I suggest that you take a look at ckanext-publicamundi, where you can
>   find some basic configuration examples to begin with.

I hope it helps to anyone in this situation :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug with ckanext-vectorstorer. That module was removed in a [previous commit](https://github.com/PublicaMundi/ckanext-vectorstorer/commit/a0b5c9f17a9467d330bb3a9c457c52b48953c217) but there is still code trying to call it in [master](https://github.com/PublicaMundi/ckanext-vectorstorer/blob/master/ckanext/vectorstorer/resource_actions.py#L13)

You should [file an issue](https://github.com/PublicaMundi/ckanext-vectorstorer/issues)